# How to list available cellular networks and connect to them manually?

Tags: android, android-networking

I want it to be like going to settings-->Mobile networks-->network operators, so the phone will search for the available operators.

I want to know how to list these inside my application and connect to any one of the
 operators I want.
 I have also tried searching for some guidelines but couldn't find the exact info I am looking for.

Comment: Wouldn't a phone only have one Cellular Network that it could connect to?

Comment: You can set the network operator manually too,this is useful incase if ur operator doesnt have a cell tower in remote areas n ur mobile doest hav a connection to the cell tower(operator specific),at tat time u could search for operators by going through the above settings.